# jquery - onclick copy to textbox

Tags: jquery, click, listener

I am trying to copy text from list item in unordered list to a text box.

```
<div class='this_section_is_created_dynamically_and_repeats_up_to_99_times'>
<label>Serial</label>
<input name="part" class= "part" type="text">
<ul>
    <li class="pattern"><a href="#" class="clickme">test1</a></li>
    <li class="pattern"><a href="#" class="clickme">test2</a></li>
</ul> 

<script>

$('.clickme').live('click', function() {                

            alert($(this).text());  // this works
        // try to copy value clicked to input box. these do not work
        $(this).prevAll('[input:text]').val($(this).text()); 
        $(this).prev(":text").val($(this).text()); 
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`prev()` and `prevAll()` look at siblings. The input is a sibling of your `ul` which is the parent of your `li`s which are the parents of your `anchors`:

These should work:

```
$(this).parent().parent().prev("input:text").val($(this).text());
```

Or:

```
$(this).parents('ul').first().prev('input:text').val($(this).text());
```

You could also give your `input` an id and just select it directly rather than traversing the DOM.

PS. You should close your input tag: `<input name="part" class= "part" type="text" />`

Comment: He should also close his script tag and div.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$('.clickme').live('click', function(e) {
    $(".part").val($(this).html()); 
});
```

You could shorten your query by referring to the element by it's id or class.
Also, you could try something like this to get the specific element...

```
$('.clickme').live('click', function(e) {
    $(this).parent().parent().prev().val($(this).html());
});
```

This goes to the parent(li) of the targetted element(a), then the parent of that element(ul), then the previous sibling of the element(input).

Comment: `this` is bound to the jQuery object that the handler was bound to (`$('.clickme')`). jQuery does that for you. So the paragraph about using e.target is wrong (it works, but might as well just take advantage of the fact that jQuery sets `this` for you), and `live()` isn't needed here either.

Comment: "`this` in your example is referring to the function"? `this` does refer to the `.clickme` element being clicked. Using `e.target` wouldn't work well if the click is done on a children of the `.clickme` element

Comment: Ah, I was unaware of that. Thanks for the info, I'll edit my post. :)

Comment: PaulPRO: .live is not needed in this extract, but in my project, these sections are  created dynamically.  .delegate may be even better!